# custom gson deserializer for nested pojo

Tags: java, json, gson, deserialization, android

How do I use fields from current json object and pass it to custom constructor of the next object. If I use default deserialization using gson, it works fine for the fields which have the same name, but since my room pojo has fields streetName and houseName(i want to store which house and street it belongs to), i want to add that while deserializing. How do I do this? I have a json which looks like this:

```
{
  "database": {
    "name": "",
    "email": "",
    "password": "",
    "streets": {
      "streetName1": {
        "houseName1": {
          "room1": {
            "roomMembers": 3
          }
        },
        "houseName2": {
          "room2": {
            "roomMembers": 2
          }
        }
      },
      "streetName2": {
        "houseName3": {
          "room3": {
            "roomMembers": 1
          },
          "room4": {
            "consumption": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My pojos are as follows:

**Street.java**

```
    public class Street{
    String streetName;
    List<House> houseList;


   ///getters and setters
    }
```

**House.java**

```
    public class House{
    String houseName;
    String streetName; //this is what I want to set using a different constructor
    List<Room> roomList;


   ///getters and setters
    }
```

**Room.java**

```
public class Room{
String roomName;    
String houseName;//this is what I want to set using a different 
     constructor

String streetName; //this is what I want to set using a different 
     constructor
 int roomMembers;


   ///getters and setters
    }
```

Comment: when are you trying to build the object top to bottom you can try and populate the lower level objects then move up the ladder ? First try and get all the objects from the json and then populate rooms then add room to list of room and then so forth

Comment: If I populate each room first, how would I know the streetName and houseName. I have to deserialize the house and street first. That's what I think. This is to be done with custom deserialization using custom constructors but I couldn't figure how to do it for nested objects

Comment: like you can use house.addRoomList(add room here)

Comment: You're not getting me. There's no problem creating the lists. There's problem getting the variables in the room java object

Comment: where is the room object in the json can you point ouit

Comment: try to use Pair<String,Street>